# Does a Pandora thumbs up show on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, pandora

I want to use the thumbs up option on Pandora but don't want it to show on Facebook - do the thumbs up show on Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you have set up your [Privacy Settings on Pandora](http://www.pandora.com/account/privacy).

[image: Pandora Privacy Settings]

Just keep "Likes" unchecked.